# How to create records in a reference table automatically with prism createMany()

Tags: typescript, sqlite, next.js, prisma

I'm creating a simple financial control application with Next.js, Typescript, Prisma orm and SQLite. I have 2 models. Transaction and Installment. I'm trying to make the installments automatically created when the transaction is created. I imagined that I would just use Prisma's createMany() method and things would work fine, but I receive a code 500 error when I try to register a transaction. I'm using eslint and the file didn't trigger any syntax/type errors. transactions and installments are returning the values correctly as seen in console.log()

```
// schema.prisma
model Transaction {
  id                   String        @id @default(uuid())
  userId               String
  title                String
  description          String?
  category             String
  value                Float
  cardFlag             String
  paymentMethod        String
  installmentsQuantity Int?
  date                 DateTime
  cardIsClosed         Boolean?
  installments         Installment[]
}

model Installment {
  id            String      @id @default(uuid())
  date          DateTime
  value         Float
  transaction   Transaction @relation(fields: [transactionId], references: [id])
  transactionId String
}
```

```js
// /api/transactions/route.ts
export async function POST(request: Request) {
  try {
    const transaction = await request.json()

    let installments: { date: Date; value: number }[] = []

    if (transaction.paymentMethod === 'Crédito') {
      const installmentsValue =
        transaction.value / transaction.installmentsQuantity

      installments = Array.from(
        { length: transaction.installmentsQuantity },
        () => {
          return {
            date: transaction.date,
            value: installmentsValue
          }
        }
      )
    }

    console.log(installments)
    console.log(transaction)

    const newTransaction = await prisma.transaction.create({
      data: {
        ...transaction,
        installment: {
          createMany: {
            data: installments
          }
        }
      },
      include: {
        installments: true
      }
    })

    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify(newTransaction), {
      status: 201,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    })
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.code === 'P2002') {
      return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify('Transaction already exists'), {
        status: 409
      })
    }

    return new NextResponse(error.message, { status: 500 })
  }
}
```

```bash
[
  { date: '2023-10-10T00:00:00.000Z', value: 100 },
  { date: '2023-10-10T00:00:00.000Z', value: 100 },
  { date: '2023-10-10T00:00:00.000Z', value: 100 }
]
{
  title: 'Test',
  description: '',
  category: 'Mercado',
  value: 300,
  paymentMethod: 'Crédito',
  cardFlag: 'Visa',
  installmentsQuantity: 3,
  date: '2023-10-10T00:00:00.000Z',
  userId: 'user_2WEVdNNOMsHXAC3u91fGyS1gJsC'
}
```

```bash
"Invalid `prisma.transaction.create()` invocation:

{
   date: {
     title: "Test",
     description: "",
     category: "Food",
     value: 200,
     paymentMethod: "Credit",
     cardFlag: "Visa",
     installmentsQuantity: 2,
     date: "2023-10-10T00:00:00.000Z",
     userId: "user_2WEVdNNOMsHXAC3u91fGyS1gJsC",
     installments: {
       createMany: {
       ~~~~~~~~~~
         date: [
           {
             date: "2023-10-10T00:00:00.000Z",
             value: 100
           },
           {
             date: "2023-10-10T00:00:00.000Z",
             value: 100
           }
         ]
       },
? create?: InstallmentCreateWithoutTransactionInput | InstallmentCreateWithoutTransactionInput[] | InstallmentUncheckedCreateWithoutTransactionInput | InstallmentUncheckedCreateWithoutTransactionInput[],
? connectOrCreate?: InstallmentCreateOrConnectWithoutTransactionInput | InstallmentCreateOrConnectWithoutTransactionInput[],
? connect?: InstallmentWhereUniqueInput | InstallmentWhereUniqueInput[]
     }
   },
   include: {
     installments: true
   }
}

Unknown argument `createMany`. Available options are listed in green."
```

Comment: "but something went wrong." What went wrong when you tried that code? Did you get an type error? A runtime error? What unexpected database state did you end up with?

Comment: I receive a code 500 error when I try to register a transaction. I'm using eslint and the file didn't trigger any syntax/type errors. transactions and installments are returning the values correctly as seen in console.log().

Comment: A `500` is an internal server error, which means there's a runtime error in your server process. What does the server console say? There should be a description of the error streamed as command line output.

Comment: in my terminal I just receive the prism logs. However, exploring the error in the browser console I found "Unknown argument `createMany`."

Comment: "The prisma logs" probably have an error that has information. And that "Unknown argument createMany." that error sounds important. What is the full text of that error? What is the stack trace of that error?

Comment: Prisma logs are just the queries it executes. No error logs. I've updated the question with the entire answer obtained from the browser error.

Comment: I solve the problem with `installments: {
          create: installments
        }`